# Select a file from user local machine in .Net MVC C# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .Net MVC C# web application. User needs to select files and uploads to server. For simplicity, let's assume just 1 file a time. Before upload the file, I want to check where the file comes from. In order to do that, I need to get the file's full path on local machine to validate the file. The path has all the information for the validation.

So, the question is: how we can have user select a file from local machine, and we can get its full path? Is it possible?

Or, this is impossible in web application and has to be done in desktop application?

Thanks

Comment: You can't get the client file's full path for security reasons.  Upload the file to the server and then do your processing.

Comment: Is this a public website? Or is it deployed on your business intranet?

Comment: Why don't you just ask the user for some of the information you need?  Make it part of the upload process.

Comment: intranet, but may need to make it public accessible.

Comment: If it's on the Intranet, you can give the server permissions to access the user's filesystem, and have the server directly access the client machine's files rather than going through the browser. I don't particularly recommend that, but it's an option.

Comment: This may be a non-sequeter, but uh, would this be part of the Model, the View, or the Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't for security reasons. It might have been possible on older browsers, but modern versions won't allow it.

In Chrome it won't even display the file path of a selected file in the control, instead showing C:\fakepath

Comment: What if we do not use upload control? is there anyway to get the full path of a local file? or, impossible?